# Does it make sense to create materialized view for table that updates few times in second?

Tags: database, performance, oracle, materialized-views

I have a big table and view bulds with complex query. The main problem that retrieving data from view is slow (6 rows for 2 sec).

I have heard that materialised view is super fast. But my table is updating few time in second (pretty often). And requirement for view that data should always be up to dated.

For now main table (view should build on) have about 100 000 row and will grows in future.

So does it make sense to use materialize view? 
Because as far I understand materialized view will rebuild each time when data is comes so few time in second and performance can be even worth that in default view.

Comment: probably you should speed up the view. can you post it in the question with the execution plan?

Comment: a materialized view is a snapshot in time.  Data in the snapshot table will be as of the time you built or refreshed the mat view, but can query like a normal table (w/ indexes and all).  If you MUST have latest data always, then post your SQL to optimize

Answer (score 4):

Materialized Views (MV) can be beneficial or detrimental to performance, depending upon how they're used. Nothing is ever `FAST:=TRUE` in Oracle.

Your requirement is that the view always be up-to-date. Then for your situation the MV must be refreshed for every commit. The question is, how often is the data queried compared to how often it is updated? You have to "pay" the computational cost somewhere - either during update or query. If you query a lot more than you update, then a MV will likely improve the performance as the complex computation will occur less often. However, if the table is updated frequently and queries seldom, then you'll be pay a penalty for every update and your performance will likely fall.

If you are having to wait 2 seconds to retrieve 6 rows, then you should consider reviewing the query, it's execution plan, and your schema's structure. 100k rows is pretty "small" and whe